# "Cannot set device ring parameters: Operation not supported"

Tags: linux, centos6, hp, nic, multicast

I'm trying to change the RX and TX for an HP BL460C server by using ethtool and get the following:

```
ethtool -G eth0 rx 4078 tx 4078
Cannot set device ring parameters: Operation not supported
```

My driver information is as follows:

```
driver: be2net                                                       
version: 10.2r                                                      
firmware-version: 12.0.1110.11 
bus-info: 0000:06:00.0                                              
supports-statistics: yes                                            
supports-test: yes                                                  
supports-eeprom-access: yes                                         
supports-register-dump: yes                                         
supports-priv-flags: no`
```

> CentOS release 6.6

The adjustments are needed for a multicast application we are running on this server.

Comment: Your system is out of date. Update the system first.

Comment: I had updated it to 6.9 and 6.10 but wasn't able to do it on either version

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the parameters to the interface configuration files and reboot?

That would be adding a line like the following to the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ethX` files.

```
ETHTOOL_OPTS="-G ${DEVICE} rx 4078 tx 4078"
```

Another option is passing the values to the be2net module in the modprobe setup. [Here's an example](https://community.hpe.com/t5/Networking/Dropped-packets-with-an-NC550SFP-card-in-a-ProLiant-DL360-G7/td-p/4740607#.XIuuqC2ZPxI).

`insmod be2net.ko rx_frag_size=value` or in `/etc/modprocbe.d/be2net.conf`:

```
options be2net rx_frag_size=value
```

Also see HPE's advisory: https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=mmr_kc-0106342